# Does NUnit's AreEqual test for reference equality or value equality?

Tags: f#, nunit

In NUnit 2.6.4 Does `AreEqual` test for reference equality or value equality? I'm confused it appears to be testing value equality in some of my tests:

```
    let result = xml |> objectProvider.Parse |> parseClassificationsFromList
    let expectedResults = [[Classification (Id "_511175266", [], Primary)]]

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults, result)
```

But in some cases:

```
    let parsedXML = xml |> objectProvider.Parse
    let results = funds parsedXML

    let fS = XElement.Parse("""
            <sectiondiv>
                <p>.....</p>
            </sectiondiv>""", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
    let f = [|NewFunds(None, objectProvider.Sectiondiv(fS))|]
    
    let expected = f;
    let result = results;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

I am getting told:

```
 Expected and actual are both <Funds[1]>
      Values differ at index [0]
```

Which would indicate it is testing reference equality. I'm totally confused! In the latter case I know the values are the same because if I convert to the expected and actual results to JSON they match.

`NewFunds` is defined as:

```
type Funds =
      | NewFunds of Specificity option * objectProvider.Sectiondiv
```

Comment: How is `NewFunds` defined?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin it's defined as follows `type Funds = | NewFunds of Specificity option * objectProvider.Sectiondiv`

Comment: It uses whatever equality the type defines, so it should be value equality for normal F# types. However, `AreEqual` is not type-safe, so make sure you are giving it values of the same type (e.g. not confusing lists and arrays). You could also just try adding `printfn "%A" (expected = actual)` to make sure nothing odd is going on. For any more help, you'll need to provide minimal reproducible example though.

Comment: `objectProvider.Sectiondiv` looks like a provided type. What is `objectProvider`?

Answer (score 1):

For basic equality, NUnit uses whatever definition of equality the provided type has implemented, usually through overriding `Equals` but possibly by implementing the `IEQuatable<T>` interface. If the object has done neither of those things, then you have reference equality for a reference type, value equality for a value type.

Except...

NUnit has it's own definition of equality for collections. Based on the error message, it looks like that's what your `NewFunds` object is. NUnit implements equality in this case as equality of each of the members of the collection, taken in order.

Note: It's more complicated than that, there are lots of special cases, but I think what I listed are the cases that impact your example.

Comment: While it might seem friendlier to have conversations in answers, [the community decided long ago to remove noisy comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267387/2370483)